# How to concatenate values from postgis table which have the same id into a new column?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query

I have the following table in postgres-9.3 postgis 2.1. (geom values is too long , I cut to make it short in below table):

```
id | name | geom
-------------------------
12 | A    | "01030000000"  
12 | B    | "01030000000" 
12 | C    | "01030000000" 
12 | D    | "01030000000" 
34 | E    | "050000005B41"
34 | F    | "050000005B41"
34 | G    | "050000005B41"
```

I would like to group and concatenate all the values into one column where they have the same id number. Expected result as below:

```
id | all_name    | geom
----------------------------
12 | A,B,C,D | "01030000000" 
34 | E,F,G   | "050000005B41"
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: It's mostly a PostgreSQL question. There is a similar question and correct answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query (this should have been a comment, not an answer)

Comment: Pure database questions are better researched/asked in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Thusly:

```
SELECT 
  Max(id) AS id, 
  array_to_string(array_agg(name), ',') AS all_name, 
  geom
FROM thetable
GROUP BY geom;
```

The only fiddly bit is there's no nice way to get the geometry and id group the grouping together cleanly, so ended up only grouping on geom. If there was a "max(geometry)" aggregate or something it would be easier to group by "id" and just take one of the geometry values that way.

Comment: If grouping by the ID is prefered, then a sub query with a LIMIT in the SELECT statement could be used, eg. `SELECT ... (SELECT geom FROM thetable b WHERE a.id = b.id LIMIT 1) AS geom FROM thetable a ...`